# 2FA with VS Code Remote-SSH?

Tags: visual-studio-code, two-factor-authentication

I am using the [Remote-SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension in Visual Studio Code to connect to a remote machine. This remote machine is protected by Duo's two-factor authentication. When I SSH in a terminal (outside of VS Code), I'm able to log-in perfectly - the terminal prompts me through the 2FA process. However, inside VS Code when I'm using the extension, I am not able to log-in. After typing in my SSH hostname and ID, the VS Code interface prompts me for my password over and over again, and does not proceed beyond that point.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I'd love to know if there is an existing solution. Unfortunately, 2FA is managed by my company and I can't turn it off.

Answer (score 9):

Got to settings in VS Code and enable this setting, **remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal**. This pulls up the terminal so that sign in via 2FA that way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this but doesn't seem to work. I'm using Code in WSL to Remote Explore into an OSX laptop. Having updated the showLoginTerminal setting, I now see the terminal appear in the bottom pane. But after I enter the password, the connection terminates with "[21:04:08.803] Failed to parse remote port from server output"

Comment: @a5af I dont know if you have found a solution yet. I did a little searching and others have reported similar errors. This [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5111) has 2 solutions and maybe one of them will work for you. Best Regards.

Answer (score 7):

I run into the same problem and fixed it by using SSH ControlMaster for Single Singe-On.

If you connect to the relevant machine using `<user_name>@<host_name>` you can simply add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host <nickname>
    User <user_name>
    HostName <host_name>
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
```

If you now open up a new session in your terminal running `ssh <nickname>` you will be asked for the password and the 2FA key. But all other subsequent ssh sessions (including svn, rsync, etc. that run over ssh) will piggyback off the initial connection without the need for re-authentication.

You can now in VS Code, select `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...` from the Command Palette (F1, ⇧⌘P) and simply enter: `<nickname>` and ControlMaster will automatically connect you using the already standing connection.
[image]

In my case, the nickname that I choose is "ody". After connecting VSC's Remote Development extension shows the following in the bottom left corner and lets me browse the files on the remote machine.

[image]

From the [FASCR](https://docs.rc.fas.harvard.edu/kb/using-ssh-controlmaster-for-single-sign-on/):

Note that all subsequent connections are dependent on the initial connection — if you exit or kill the initial connection all other ones die, too. This can obviously be annoying if it happens accidentally. It’s easily avoided by setting up a master connection in the background:

`ssh -CX -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -fN <nickname>`

The -fN make it go into the background and sit idle, after authenticating. (C for compression,Y for X forwarding, and o ServerAliveInterval=30 to prevent dropped connections have nothing to do with the ControlMaster but are almost always helpful.)

Note that all port forwarding, including X display forwarding, must be setup by the initial connection and cannot be changed.

Comment: Unfortunately control master doesn't seem to work on Windows.

Comment: Oh, that might be. I only checked on MacOS. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~/.ssh/config` file to configure your hostnames and keys. But I don't know if there is a way to save passwords for convenience.